# Which is better or easy framework for making rest API Node.js or Django Rest?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, django-rest-framework

I am a beginner and develop a mobile and web application. technology that we use for it is Open CV for Vision, React Native for mobile application and React for the web application. I am confused in choosing the best framework for making rest API Node.js or Django Rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thie is a very opinionated question, but consider two things:

- node.js is an environmen for a programming language (JavaScript)
- Django rest framework is a framework (on top of Django) specifically aimed at generating REST api’s.

Unless you find something that compares to rest framework for node.js, I would recommend going for the latter (Django rest framework).

But once again, this is an opinionated question.

Comment: Give me ten minutes and I can set up models (database), views(in combinations with the urls.py) which give you an api url.  On top of that you can easily deploy a django based application to heroku or similar services.  On top of that it's quite easy to integrate MySQL or even easier, Postgres SQL. On top of this I'm a total noob programmer, so it's probably even easier for someone with actual experience.  On top of that the docs are very well written.  On top of that....